Why doesn't the axiom of infinity imply that of the empty set?
Wikipedia states the axiom of infinity as follows:
∃I (∃o (o ∈ I ∧ ¬∃n (n ∈ o)) ∧ ∀x (x ∈ I ⇒ ∃y (y ∈ I ∧ ∀a (a ∈ y ⇔ (a ∈ x ∨ a = x)))))

Now, the part
∃o (o ∈ I ∧ ¬∃n (n ∈ o))

is saying that there exists a set that is empty (and that this set is also in I, but this is not relevant here.) Isn't the axiom of the empty set redundant, then?

Note that this formulation of the Axiom of Infinity does prove the existence of an empty set, and Extensionality is enough to get its uniqueness. Some formulations assume the existence of the empty set, as well as finite unions and set roster notation, which have to be proven to exist/be definable in terms of just the logical operators and membership. One such version is: ∃I(∅∈I∧∀y(y∈I→y∪{y}∈I)).

Wikipedia definition of ZFC with 9 axioms which explicitly says 'axiom of empty set' is redundant and not in the list, SEP has another equivalent formulation. the axiom schema of specification can be used to prove the existence of the empty set, denoted ∅, once at least one set is known to exist. One way to do this is to use a property φ which no set has. It is common to make a definitional extension that adds the symbol ∅ to the language of ZFC. So Axiom of infinity can freely express ∅ without concern...

It  does.
Infinity, in the form that does not use the empty set symbol: ∅, states that there is a set.
In general, if there is at least one set S we can use Separation to carve out from it the empty set as {y∈S : y≠y} or any other unsatisfiable condition.
See John Burgese, Set Theory (2022), page 10:

Separation gives us the empty set, since given any set u at all – and even pure logic assumes there is at least one item in the domain our quantifiers range over, which in the present case consists of sets – separation gives { x ∈ u : x ∉ u }, which is empty.


This answer is a bit terse..... I think that this comment from the question you link to provides a nice theorem with a simple proof that you've sketched here.  "Theorem: The existence of any set and the axiom of separation imply the empty set."  This answer would benefit by being a little more explicit in this regard, while not having to be much longer.
